# How to print if first condition is not met?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm practicing conditionals and logical operators.

How do I make the following rock, paper, scissors game print "This is not a valid object selection." immediately after Player 1's input, if Player 1 enters an invalid object? Right now the string is not printed until both players have entered an object.

Also, any suggestions for making the following code more elegant?

```
player1 = input('Player 1? ')
player2 = input('Player 2? ')

if (player1.lower() == 'rock' and
    player2.lower() == 'rock'):
    print('Tie.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'rock' and
    player2.lower() == 'paper'):
    print('Player 2 wins.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'rock' and
    player2.lower() == 'scissors'):
    print('Player 1 wins.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'paper' and
    player2.lower() == 'paper'):
    print('Tie.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'paper' and
    player2.lower() == 'scissors'):
    print('Player 2 wins.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'paper' and
    player2.lower() == 'rock'):
    print('Player 1 wins.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'scissors' and
    player2.lower() == 'scissors'):
    print('Tie.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'scissors' and
    player2.lower() == 'rock'):
    print('Player 2 wins.')
elif (player1.lower() == 'scissors' and
    player2.lower() == 'paper'):
    print('Player 1 wins.')
else:
    print('This is not a valid object selection.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a function to ask each player their choice? Only if the player enters a valid selection will they be allowed to proceed through the code to your logic statements.

```
def get_choice(Player_number):
    print('Player', Player_number, 'please enter your choice: ', end='')
    while True:
        choice = input().lower()        #lower converts input to all lowercase
        if choice in ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors'):   # check if valid choice 
            return choice   # if valid return choice
        else:
            print('Incorrect choice, try again: ', end='')  # else print this and start loop agan

player1 = get_choice('1')
player2 = get_choice('2')
```

For the logic part, note that if player1 choice == player 2 choice, this will substitute 3 elif blocks in your code, ie.

```
if player1 == player2:
    print('tie')
```

Now replaces pl==rock and p2 == rock, p1 == scissors and p2 == scissors, ect.

edit:

1) The problem if you move the print statement in 2 to inside the input in 4 is you can no longer specify the ,end='' parameter, as it does not work with input. As you said it will generate SyntaxError. The code looks much cleaner when run this way in terminal as it all lines up, but do test it for yourself.

2) end='' prints an empty string at the end of the print statement. you are confusing this with end='\n' which prints a new line after print. As my way keeps the cursor on the same line after the print, it lines up with the input to make it look nice, see above question. Note the print statement in python by default passes , end='\n'. This is why

```
print('hello')    #same as print('hello', end='\n')
print('world)
hello
world

print('hello', end='')
print('world', end='')
helloworld
```

3) The while True loop will alway evaluate to true. So the body of the while loop will constantly cycle - However, it can return out of the entire function with the 'return choice' function. The only way to leave this function if to get down the logical steps required to reach the return statement. In this case unless the choice is in that tuple('rock', 'paper', 'scisors') it will just print invalid entry try again, finishing the block. However, As while is still true the loop will begin again and ask the user to input again. This will repeat until a valid choice is selected.

4) You could concatenate it onto the player_number eg..

```
print('Player', Player_number + ',' , 'please enter your choice: ', end='')
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't made my way to functions yet, but I think I understand most of the syntax. A few questions, though: 1) Could the code in print() in line 2 somehow be inserted in the input() in line 4 instead? I tried, but received a syntax error. 2) I thought the use of end='' by default would create a new line after the print statement? But this seems to do the opposite. Can you explain why? 3) Why the use of the while-loop in line 3? Doesn't it just have to run through the code once?

Comment: 4) If I wanted a comma right after Player_number in line 2, how is that achieved? I can't figure out how to avoid the whitespace.

Comment: Check my edit, I've tried to answer the questions. Please accept my answer, thanks!